# How to modify the appearance of some types of entries in the formatted bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, french, apacite

I have to replace the mention *In* with *Dans* in the @inbook field of my bibliography, in order to follow some french rules. How could I do that? Thanks a lot!

This is an entry:

```
@inbook{AnnieAnzieu2010,
   author = {Anzieu, Annie},
   title = {Questions sur la nature et les fonctions des images},
   booktitle = {Des images pour la pensée},
   editor = {Anzieu, Annie and Passone, Sesto Marcello},
   publisher = {Éditions In Press},
   address = {Paris},
   pages = {29-39},
   year = {2010},
}



\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}



\begin{document}


    Comme l'écrit Annie Anzieu \cite{AnnieAnzieu2010}, ...




\bibnewpage 
{%start grouping
  \doublespacing % <====================================================
  \raggedright 
  \nocite{}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite} 
  \bibliography{Library}
}%end grouping

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't do this by modifying the `.bib` entry, you will have to use the interfaces of your bibliography style (if any). We need to know which bibliography package you use (`cite`, `natbib`, `biblatex`, ...) and which style you use (the argument of `\bibliographystyle` for BibTeX-based packages or the value of the `style` option for `biblatex`). Please show us a complete example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)

Comment: Why do you want to replace `In`? It's commonly used in French bibliographies, as  a Latin adverb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apacite` citation management package automatically loads the auxiliary file `french.apc` if the `babel` package was loaded with the option `french`. As you can probably guess, `french.apc` contains lots of customizations for french-language bibliographies. On line 83 of the file `french.apc`, one finds the following instruction:

```
\renewcommand{\BIn}{In}%                 % for ``In'' editor...
```

Since you prefer `Dans` over `In`, I suggest you issue the instruction

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BIn}{Dans}}
```

in the preamble, *after* loading the `apacite` package.

By the way, for the entry at hand, I believe the entry *type* should be `@incollection`, not `@inbook`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Library.bib}
@incollection{AnnieAnzieu2010,
  author   = {Anzieu, Annie},
  title    = {Questions sur la Nature et les Fonctions des Images},
  booktitle= {Des Images Pour La Pensée},
  editor   = {Anzieu, Annie and Passone, Sesto Marcello},
  publisher= {Éditions In Press},
  address  = {Paris},
  pages    = {29--39},
  year     = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, twoside=semi, headings=small,
               chapterprefix=true, listof=flat]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % 'mathptmx' is borderline deprecated
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BIn}{Dans}} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\raggedright 
\bibliography{Library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, but I did not try to modify the auxiliary file. I just put some piece of code into the preamble. But, when I do that in my main file, it does not work : \AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BIn}{Dans}%
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Consulté le {#1}, de\ }%
\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Consulté sur\ }%
}

Comment: @domi - Please see the update to the answer I posted. Incidentally, judging by lines 118 and 119 in `french.apc`, it doesn't look like you're really modifying `\BRetrievedFrom`.

Comment: @Mico: Not replacing `In` with `Dans` is probably not an oversight, as the Latin adverb `In` is (was?)  commonly used in French bibliographies.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks!!! Bernard: Right, but I have to adapt in French some new bibliographic rules.

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks. I'll edit my answer to remove this unnecessary qualification.

Comment: ... Finally, it does not work since all my dates disappeared in the in-text citation \cite{Anzieu2010}. The result is: (Anzieu,). What could I do?

Comment: @domi - Please provide more information regarding what exactly you're doing. For sure, if I replace `\nocite{*}` in the code shown above with `\cite{AnnieAnzieu2010}`, I get `(Anzieu, 2010)`, *not*  `(Anzieu,)`.

Comment: But I have to use \nocite{} and even if I use \nocite{*}, it doesn't work.

Comment: @domi - Please explain how you get `(Anzieu,)` when running `\nocite`. The whole point of `\nocite` is to *produce no citation call-out*...

Comment: I can't explain it as I did exactly what it is said here.

Comment: @Mico ...of great value. It was my fault and the fault of \usepackage{hyperref} which has to be inserted just before : \usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BIn}{Dans}} % <-- new
\bibliographystyle{apacite}. Now it works!